# Rust lifetime annotation for trait implementation

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn rust by doing some exercises. One issue that I'm stumbling up is the lifetime annotation, which in the following example gives me a fit:

```
struct GenMatrix<T> {
    dim: (usize, usize),
    data: Vec<T>
}

impl <T> ops::Index<usize> for GenMatrix<T> {
    type Output = &[T];

    fn index(&self, row: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        
        return & self.data[row * self.dim.1..(row + 1) * self.dim.1];
    }
}
```

In the sixth line, the compiler doesn't let me define the output as `type Output = &[T]` with the following error:

`` `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here explicit lifetime name needed here ``

I've tried to life-annotate GenMatrix itself and its data member and tried to make to life-annotate the ops::Index declaration as well. Neither worked. How is it possible to solve this?

Comment: I think you meant `type Output = [T]`, you're already adding a reference in the method `index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you should use `type Output = [T]`, because the `&` reference is already added at the function itself:

```rust
use std::ops;

struct GenMatrix<T> {
    dim: (usize, usize),
    data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> ops::Index<usize> for GenMatrix<T> {
    type Output = [T];

    fn index(&self, row: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        return &self.data[row * self.dim.1..(row + 1) * self.dim.1];
    }
}
```

---

Note that this is a short-hand version for:

```rust
impl<T> ops::Index<usize> for GenMatrix<T> {
    type Output = [T];

    fn index<'a>(&'a self, row: usize) -> &'a Self::Output {
        return &self.data[row * self.dim.1..(row + 1) * self.dim.1];
    }
}
```

Meaning, the output of `index` has the same lifetime as its `self` parameter, which is what you want.